# Mongoid, scope if a value is set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm creating a scope in my rails app, I want my scope to return documents which have anything set for the field in question.

```
scope :address_available, where(:address => "")
```

So because some documents might not have that field defined, and others will have a string as the value. But how can I return the documents which are not `nil`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`exists`](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html)

```
scope :address_available, where(:address.exists => true)
```